# iOS speaker output format (iPhone)

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, format, streaming

I want to playback audio data received from the network. 
My incoming audio PCM data are in the format Int16, 1 channel, sample rate 8000, 160 bytes/package

Now I'm not sure, which audio format iOS is supporting on the speaker side?
IMHO I have to work with Float32 and the sample rate 44.100 / 48000 is that right?

So I think I have to convert my Int16 linear PCM data to Float32. 
Maybe I have also tu resample the data from 8k to 48k, I'm not sure (maybe the hardware does it).

Could someone help me? 
Here is my current code, where I build the AVAudioPCMBuffer.

```
func convertInt16ToFloat32(_ data: [Int16]) -> AVAudioPCMBuffer {
        let audioBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: outputFormat!, frameCapacity: 160)!

        // Each real data of the array input is reduced to the interval [-1, 1]
        for i in 0..<data.count {
            // Convert the buffer to floats. (before resampling)
            let div: Float32 = (1.0 / 32768.0)
            let floatKiller = div * Float32(i)

            audioBuffer.floatChannelData?.pointee[i] = floatKiller
        }

        audioBuffer.frameLength = audioBuffer.frameCapacity
        return audioBuffer
    }
```

And on the other side I play back the created AVAudioPCMBuffer in my AVAudioEngine.

```
func playFromNetwork(data: [Int16]) {
        // data: linear data PCM-Int16, sample rate 8000, 160 bytes
        let audio = convertInt16ToFloat32(data)
        // playback converted data on AVAudioPlayerNode
        self.playerNode!.scheduleBuffer(audio, completionHandler: nil)
        Logger.Audio.log("Play audio data .....")
}
```

Here is my setup for AVAudioEngine:

```
func initAudio() {
        try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)

        engine = AVAudioEngine()
        playerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()

        engine!.attach(playerNode!)
        engine!.connect(playerNode!, to: engine!.mainMixerNode, format: outputFormat)
        engine!.prepare()

        try! engine!.start()
        playerNode!.play()
    }
```

Comment: and what exactly is not working?

Comment: Currently I hear only **noise** on my speaker. Something is wrong with my output format oder something else.

Comment: Will the audio hardware resample my data internal automatically (to 48k Hz)? Or I have to resample my PCM data manually?

Comment: I forget to mention my outputFormat:

`let outputFormat = AVAudioFormat.init(commonFormat: AVAudioCommonFormat.pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 8000, channels: 1, interleaved: false)`

Comment: Bug is fixed: let floatKiller = div * Float32(data[i])

Comment: another point here: you have to work with the internal iPhone hardware format, which is pcmFloat and the internal sample rater (48 kHz)

Comment: Currently having the same issue with only getting noise (clicks etc), can you tell me how did you manage to change sample rate from 8khz to 48khz? I have the same scenario i.e. getting audio PCM data with format Int16, 1 channel, sample rate 8000, 160 bytes/package. I read and decode rtp to int16 array (with lookup table), pass it to PCMbuffer, populate mono->stereo, and int16 to float32. (Trying it with simulator currently).

Comment: You have to set the right format for your output engine, in your case you could also set directly let outputFormat = AVAudioFormat.init(commonFormat: AVAudioCommonFormat.pcmFormatInt16, sampleRate: 8000, channels: 1, interleaved: false)